# how to read and search for a keyword in an fts file?

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python program that opens an fts file, searches for a keyword and prints the value next to it. For example, the program will search for "OBSERVER=" in the file and print out a name.

I have gotten this to work successfully in a txt file but am having trouble with the fts file.

```
file = open("text.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    if "OBSERVER=" in line:
        str = line.partition('\'')[-1].rpartition('\'')[0]
        print str
    if "IMAGETYP=" in line:
        str2 = line.partition('\'')[-1].rpartition('\'')[0]
        print str2
    if "READOUTM=" in line:
        str3 = line.partition('\'')[-1].rpartition('\'')[0] 
        print str3
file.close()
```

What libraries must I use for python to be able to open, read, search and print the strings inside an fts file?

Comment: You should post a sample line of text.txt

Comment: is it an .fts or .fits file? if it is .fits (or .fit), which I suspect given the keywords you mention, you can use `pyfits`

Comment: What does *"(...) having trouble with the fts file."* mean? Any errors? Is it a text or binary format?

Comment: The program needs to be able to open both .fts and .fits. The error I received is,AttributeError: module 'pyfits' has no attribute 'getheader'

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using a module called `pyfits`. First, you install the module. Then, let me know if this works:

```
import pyfits
hdr = pyfits.getheader(filename)
print hdr['OBSERVER']
print hdr['IMAGETYP']
print hdr['READOUTM']
```

Comment: I received this error after trying your suggestion. AttributeError: module 'pyfits' has no attribute 'getheader'

Comment: @dgo1970 I don't know what version of pyfits you installed but the latest stable release (pyfits 3.3) has a `getheader` function

Comment: I figured it out, this is my new code,                                                         from astropy.io import fits
hdulist = fits.open('aMrk290-20140529-S002-R001-Exp300-R_DC_FC_CR.fits')
print(hdulist[0].header['LONPOLE']).

Comment: To do it with a .fts file, would I be able to use the same library as the code above?

Comment: @dgo1970 I don't know, why don't you try it?